# Finding the solution to a difficult integral

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

I'm struggling with solving the following type of integral

$$\int_0^t \frac{c_1}{\sqrt{2\pi x^3 }}e^{-\frac{(c_1-x)^2}{2x}}\phi\left(\frac{c_2-c_1-\sqrt{t-x}}{\sqrt{t-x}}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{t-x}}{\rm d}x,$$

where $\phi(\cdot)$ denotes the density (PDF) function of the standard normal distribution and $c_1,c_2$ are constants.

As it involves an integral over the density of a normal distribution I have tried various combinations of the PDF and CDF of the normal distribution (including the product of the two). With no success however...

Can anyone point me in the right direction to solve this type of integral?

Comment: Your integrand is constant according to $ds$

Comment: Since s only appears in the exponential part, it suffices to compute the integral of this part. The rest can be factored out.

Comment: Apologies! I confused the s with the x and the end result was a mess! I've edited the post and the problem should be much harder now ;)

Comment: How did you come across this integral in the first place?

Comment: Made it myself..